# signed NaN values

Tags: c, printf, nan

Based on "IEEE" spec :
"When either an input or result is NaN, this standard does not interpret the sign of a NaN."
However the `printf` prints `NaN` values as signed:`nan` or `-nan`
Can someone point me the set of rules(from spec?) when `nan` and when `-nan` is printed
For example , I checked that `printf(-1.0f)` prints `-nan`
Thank you

Comment: Your `printf()` example doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The underlying representation of a NaN contains a sign bit, and this is what `printf` looks at when deciding if it should print the minus or not.

The reason why the standard says that the sign bit should be ignored is to allow things like *negate* or *absolute* to simply modify the sign bit, without being forced to check if the input value was NaN.

Comment: Can you please direct me where in the spec or (some) manual it is written.

Comment: Sure, the Wikipedia article covers the underlying representation in great detail: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985

Comment: I don`t see any attitude there about -nan vs nan.The document deals with arithmetic ,not print

Comment: If the sign bit in the underlying representation is set, this particular implementation of `printf` prints `-nan`. There is no standard that says that it has to, or that it shouldn't. The C standard does not specify that a particular floating-point implementation is used, or that NaN:s behave in any special way.