# Why zero times infinity = negative nan?

Tags: c++, floating-point

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double A = 1e3000000;
    double B = 0;
    double C = A * B;

    std::cout << "A = " << A << "\n";
    std::cout << "B = " << B << "\n";
    std::cout << "C = " << C << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
A = inf
B = 0
C = -nan
```

Why is C negative? I tested this with clang 17 and also with online C++ compiler.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21349847/positive-vs-negative-nans

Comment: fun fact: compiler dependant: https://godbolt.org/z/h8sjffh9K

Comment: It's weird and (I'd agree) somewhat surprising, but it's not wrong, because the sign bit has no meaning for NaNs.

Comment: `A * B` can be done in higher precision in an optimizing compiler, resulting in different results